# Kafka - how to watch for new messages

Tags: php, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have PHP application that consumes Kafka messages.
The problem is how to know that there are new messages in Kafka?
First solution is to create consumer in PHP then run it in a loop to check new messages. Something like this

```
<?php

namespace MyAppBundle\Command;

use MyAppBundle\EventSourcing\EventSerializer\JSONEventSerializer;
use MyAppBundle\Service\EventProjectorService;
use MyAppBundle\Service\KafkaService;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException;

class EventCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('events:fetch');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        /** @var KafkaService $kafkaService */
        $kafkaService = $this->getContainer()->get('store_locator.kafka_service');
        /** @var EventProjectorService $eventProjector */
        $eventProjector = $this->getContainer()->get('store_locator.event_projector');

        while(1){
          $messages = $kafkaService->fetchEvents();

          foreach ($messages as $message) {
              $eventProjector->aggregate($message);
          }
        }
        $output->writeln("Finish");
    }
}
```

But I don't like it... Is there any other way?

If no better way, how to keep it running? For instance when something fail.

Comment: I'm actually looking for a Symfony / Kafka solution at the moment. Is there any chance you can share your kafka service code?

Comment: @Nealio I don't know what you need exactly, but I'm using `nmred/kafka-php` package and implementing everything as described in the README.

Comment: there is wrapper for kafka consumer , which continue looks for new messages and restart itself after some time as well
https://github.com/mbhamra/KafkaManager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there are no better ways than to loop infinitely and keep checking for new messages. A common approach is to have the task kill itself after a set amount of time or number of iterations and then use something like `supervisord` to detect the death and resurrect the consumer in order to prevent it eating up all your resources.

Comment: I have similar results, so I can assume that's the best solution:
1. Use supervisord to make sure service is running
2. Configure properly loggers (optionally)
3. Kill and re-run service from time to time.